# What determines a "year" in SW Universe, for age?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In The Mandalorian, it's said that the package that the Mandalorian is to pick up is "50 years old".  Given how many different planets, stars, etc. there are in the Star Wars universe, what is the "baseline" for a Year?

This discussion does point out that a "year" is certainly relative:

> "Wait. They said fifty years old."
>   "Species age differently. Perhaps it could live many centuries."
>   - "The Mandalorian" and IG-11 upon discovering an infant of the species

I found a reference to a ["Standard Year"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Standard_year):

> On Coruscant, a year was made up of twelve months[source?] spanning 365 days of 24 hours each, with no leap years. The galaxy used a standardized dating system based off of the galactic capital Coruscant. By the time of the New Republic, the Galactic calendar would use the Battle of Yavin as the epicenter on which to date years

So would it all, even in the time-frame of the Mandalorian, and beyond, still be a Corsucantian year?

Comment: Coruscant time, probably

Comment: @Valorum - I'm familiar with SW, but admit I'm not super knowledgeable, especially of its history/lore/etc...Was Corsucant (which is/was(?) the Galactic Capital) *that* big of an influence on the Galaxy where that would logically make sense to the people in the Galaxy to use their time-frames?

Comment: @Valorum - Thanks for the Dup Closing...don't know how I missed that when searching before I asked. (IIRC it didn't show at all in the "similar questions" box that pops up when asking a question).  Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coruscanti time is the universal measurement seen in the Star Wars universe, according to the Lucasfilm Story Group's Pablo Hidalgo.

> **Q. How is time measured in the galaxy if each planet has a different time of rotation and translation?**
>
> **PH:** *We kind of have assume that there is a standard hour, there is a
> standard day, a standard week, a standard month, a unit of measurement that everyone understands how long that is. And in our storytelling we
> say that all that measurement comes from Coruscant, so not only is it
> the Galactic capital, it's sort of the yardsticks from which all time is
> measured in the Galaxy*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rebel Recon: Inside "The Future of the Force"](https://www.starwars.com/video/disneyxd-rebels-recon-inside-the-future-of-the-force)</sup></sub>

So to answer your specific question, the Child would be fifty *Coruscant* (Standard) years old.